# how can I throw an exception when casting from string to int caused precision loss?

Tags: php, precision

Is there a way to actually check before or after casting from string to int if there was precision loss and throw an exception?

```
$id = "21321312412435453453453454"
$numId = (int) $id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just used php [`predefined constants`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to compare it)

```
$id = "21321312412435453453453454";
if($id > PHP_INT_MAX)
    echo "too big";
else
    echo "okay";
```

Output:

```
too big
```

**EDIT:**

For negative you just can define the constant like this:

```
define('PHP_INT_MIN', ~PHP_INT_MAX);
```

You can read about `PHP_INT_MAX` even in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

And a quote from there:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. **PHP does not support unsigned integers**. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and **maximum** value using the constant **PHP_INT_MAX** since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Comment: what about negative ones?

Comment: So the full answer would be: 
```$id = "-21354646456456453454";
if($id > PHP_INT_MAX || $id < -PHP_INT_MAX)
    echo "too big";
else
    echo "okay";```

Is this platform independent for unsigned/signed implementations of 32-bit integers in php?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Yes (I think you mean `PHP_INT_MIN`) if you want to include/ also check for the negatives

Comment: I used ```-PHP_INT_MAX``` and I am asking if that is platform independent for builds of PHP regarding signed/unsigned. I would try to avoid defining new varialbles

Comment: @MichailMichailidis The max value is different from 32bit and 64bit otherwise you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it back to a string and compare the two.

Comment: A bit hacky but I like this approach too! +1